# How to get get parent loop elements inside child loop jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Below is the loops which i am iterating to swap the contents of two divs,

```
    $('#itemsRows ul').each(function () { 
    var $this = $(this);



    $('#wrap-ajax ul').each(function () {
       // How to get #itemsRows ul input element?

    });

   });
```

Comment: `$this` inside the second callback refer to the `#itemsRows ul` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `find` or `children` on `$this`:

```
$('#itemsRows ul').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);



    $('#wrap-ajax ul').each(function () {
        var theInput = $this.find("input");
        // Or
        var theInput = $this.children("input");
    });

});
```

...depending on whether you want descendant elements (as your question suggests; `find`), or just immediate children (`children`).

Your inner loop's iterator function closes over the context in which it's created, including your `$this` variable, so even though you're inside that inner iterator function, `$this` refers to the specific `#itemsRows ul` element for the outer loop.

More about closures (on my blog): [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)